# How to create concise and manageable search tables?

Tags: c#, java, database, search

I have a configuration table that has a number of columns (20+), most of which are nullable. I generally need to search for and identify an individual row, but each search might have different parameters. In other words, search A might request a match on ParamA, ParamF and ParamG, whilst search B might request a match on ParamA, ParamB, ParamE and ParamK.

The problem is, with every new column that is added, a whole bunch of new rows are required to provide the configuration for the various permutations.

So both the table, and the code side searching mechanism are becoming ugly and unmanageable. What other ways are there to tackle this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are actually storing in the table but I don't think that it is a good idea to keep all configuration parameters in one table. You sould separate the columns by semantics somehow and provide the relations with foreign keys. That way you only have to update one table once a new column is introduced. This is [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).